# Windows 8 Certificate Warning: We can't verify who created this file

Tags: windows, code-signing, security-warning

Despite successfully signing my C++ app on Windows 8 with signtool with a valid timestamp server and certificate, when I (local) or my users (remote) attempt to run the app, Windows displays the following message:

> Open File - Security Warning We can't verify who created this file.
>   Are you sure you want to run this file?

I am using signtool with a Comodo certificate and `sign` with options `/f`, `/p`, and `/tr`. I am confident that the signature is successful because it removes most of the runtime security warnings for my users.

'Security Warning' Dialog:

[image]

Comment: I am having a similar problem with my program that I wrote in java, if you found a fix can you let me know?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that Microsoft, in 2013, made a change to Windows such that executables opened from a network drive will ALWAYS give this warning, even if they are signed. Source (it is brought up in the comments section by Kraig Whiting): [Everything you need to know about Authenticode Code Signing - IEInternals - MSDN Blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20140414065308/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx?PageIndex=2) (archive link)

It seems the only way to make this go away is to do [what user4437298 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27863307/4518341), which is to add the network drive as a trusted zone.

Answer (score 2):

Add your z:\ drive to trusted sites in internet explorer local intranet advanced options